# How to use Multiple source Database using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, .net-6.0

I tried to use Multiple DbContext to migrate each domain of my project to deferent database like this:

```
public class AppDbContext: DbContext
.
.
public class UserAccessDbContext: DbContext
.
.
public class AdministrationDbContext: DbContext
.
.
Etc
```

but it's look like I make something wrong so I get all Tables in each DbContext, I don't have any FK that linking the domains.

My connection string for each DbContext like this:

```
public static void AppDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString) =>
   services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 27))));

  public static void UserAccessDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString) =>
   services.AddDbContext<UserAccessDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 27))));
  
  public static void AdministrationDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString) =>
   services.AddDbContext<AdministrationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 27))));
```

And my Repository like this:

```
public class AppRepository<T> : RepositoryBase<T>, IReadRepository<T>, IRepository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
{
  public AppRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext) : base(appDbContext)
  {
  }
}
.
.
.
public class AdministrationRepository<T> : RepositoryBase<T>, IReadRepository<T>, IRepository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
{
    public AdministrationRepository(AdministrationDbContext administrationdbContext) : base(administrationdbContext)
    {
    }
}
.
.
.
public class UserAccessRepository<T> : RepositoryBase<T>, IReadRepository<T>, IRepository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
{
    public UserAccessRepository(UserAccessDbContext userAccessdbContext) : base(userAccessdbContext)
    {

    }
}
```

I also registered the repo like this:

```
public class DefaultInfrastructureModule : Module
{
  private readonly bool _isDevelopment = false;
  private readonly List<Assembly> _assemblies = new List<Assembly>();

  public DefaultInfrastructureModule(bool isDevelopment, Assembly? callingAssembly = null)
  {
    _isDevelopment = isDevelopment;
    var coreAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(User)); // TODO: Replace "Project" with any type from your Core project
    var infrastructureAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(StartupSetup));
    if (coreAssembly != null)
    {
      _assemblies.Add(coreAssembly);
    }
    if (infrastructureAssembly != null)
    {
      _assemblies.Add(infrastructureAssembly);
    }
    if (callingAssembly != null)
    {
      _assemblies.Add(callingAssembly);
    }
  }

  protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    if (_isDevelopment)
    {
      RegisterDevelopmentOnlyDependencies(builder);
    }
    else
    {
      RegisterProductionOnlyDependencies(builder);
    }
    RegisterCommonDependencies(builder);
  }

  private void RegisterCommonDependencies(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    //Start Repository Reg
    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(AppRepository<>))
        .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
        .As(typeof(IReadRepository<>))
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(AdministrationRepository<>))
        .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
        .As(typeof(IReadRepository<>))
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(UserAccessRepository<>))
        .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
        .As(typeof(IReadRepository<>))
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    //End Repository Reg

    builder
        .RegisterType<Mediator>()
        .As<IMediator>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(context =>
    {
      var c = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
      return t => c.Resolve(t);
    });

    var mediatrOpenTypes = new[]
    {
      typeof(IRequestHandler<,>),
      typeof(IRequestExceptionHandler<,,>),
      typeof(IRequestExceptionAction<,>),
      typeof(INotificationHandler<>),
    };

    foreach (var mediatrOpenType in mediatrOpenTypes)
    {
      builder
      .RegisterAssemblyTypes(_assemblies.ToArray())
      .AsClosedTypesOf(mediatrOpenType)
      .AsImplementedInterfaces();
    }

    builder.RegisterType<EmailSender>().As<IEmailSender>()
      .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
  }

  private void RegisterDevelopmentOnlyDependencies(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    // TODO: Add development only services
  }

  private void RegisterProductionOnlyDependencies(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    // TODO: Add production only services
  }

}
```

What I miss in my code to fix it !

Any help how can I do it.

Comment: Take in consideration you can't have context with tables with the same name because crash classes between them, even if they are in different entitymodels.

Comment: _"so I get all Tables in each DbContext"_ can you please elaborate?

Comment: Dear @LeandroBardelli  I update my question with more details.

Comment: Dear @GuruStron may you check my update too.

Comment: Sorry @sumer5020 but we don't work in that way, we need specific question or code to help you. Please read the tutorial and guidelines on how to ask

Comment: Dear @LeandroBardelli I update my question in other way If there is another info to be more specific I will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get the question right, the case might be you're currently working on a monolith and trying to separate things out to surround each business context for further separate them out,... might be like microservices ?

I don't know about the specific reason why you would want to do that, but if the reason doesn't worth it, I suggest you avoid to doing that.

I assume you read above recommendation, and if it's the case we really need to do that, then understand these things first:

**Each DbContext can config their own entity**

Let assume we have 10 entities for 3 `DbContext`, we can separate them out 2 entities for `ADbContext`, 5 for `BDbContext` and 3 for `CDbContext`. Manage the configuration like FK, between them wisely, otherwise, that would turn to be chaos. Here is how to doing this, using fluent API

```cs
public class MyAppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<OurEntity> OurEntity { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<OurEntity>(builder => 
       {
            // Our implementation goes here...
       });
    }
}
```

Like that, we config and register only entities correspondingly with each `DbContext`.

**We need to register each DbContext separately to whatever kind of DI**

You does this above in the question, then I'll skip this part.

**Organize Migration operation for each DbContext**

I usually organize them in folder like this:

- Data/Migrations/ContextA
- Data/Migrations/ContextB
- Data/Migrations/ContextC

Each context have their own Migrations and snapshot.

Doing this by specify separate DbContext when using EF migration tool

```sh
dotnet ef migrations add [MigrationName] --context [DbContextName] --output-dir [Path to desire place to store migration]
```

then apply them separately by

```sh
dotnet ef database update [MigrationName] --context [DbContextName]
```

That's it. Of course we can do it, but I still suggest we should avoid this approach if there was no specific reason.

Comment: Dear @Gordon, my reason to work this eay is that my project dealing with big data and i need to crate one place to manage my dayly work and my other features that need huge power from Database, so i think that if i handeld my data separately between each side i can done it in perfict way

Comment: And in the other hand i need to use the principal that say "handle you data before it handled you".

Comment: If the solution was large, I strongly recommend to separate the process pipelines into smaller projects. They can be in the same folder for easier version control and deployment. 

And If the solution not tend to go as big as we consider it "complex", then I think we should be fine. Just a remind, If we built the solution from scratch, it would be easy for us(as we fully control the domains and context), but it might not for new comers afterward.

Comment: Dear @Gordon I think I miss something when I used IEntityTypeConfiguration

Comment: After hard time I catch my issue with DbContext, at first I used `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());` to config my entities but my Assembly always take all configrations for the context for some reason, I tried to use `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AccGeneralJournalConfiguration());` of OnModelCreating in each DbContext and it's work successfully, but that make me confuse a little bit.

Comment: Noo... please don't use `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly`, that would add every configs we make to the current `DbContext`. Please specify separate configuration for each `DbSet` like my example above with corresponding `DbContext`. Otherwise, we can use reflection to pick what types of configuration we want to apply for each `DbContext` then apply it through a custom extension we made. That's much nicer but much complex also.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon , now  can I Implement with `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AccGeneralJournalConfiguration());` or there is another way as the best.

Comment: `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration` should work fine, and we can separate configuration files and organize them too. The only difference here is where to centralize and organize the code. As long as it suit our taste, I think that's the best for the project, as we wrote them ourself, we know the best :D. Glad it help

Comment: btw... The best IMO is just what I typed above, make our own extensions to apply whichever configuration we need through reflection (that's also how `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly` doing behind the scene), but instead of passing assembly, we pass an array of what entities we desire to implement their config to the `DbContext`